# WSUS over https

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, windows-update

I have set up a WSUS role on a windows server 2012 R2 and it works trouble-free over http. I would like now to secure the communication with SSL over https. I generated with openssl a .pfx certificate from our company’s wildcard certificate, installed it on the server and configured IIS to use it for encryption.

Problem:

When I try to connect the WSUS console to WSUS service, I get the follow error:

[image]

I followed [this Microsoft documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852346.aspx#bkmk_3.5.ConfigSSL) to install WSUS over SSL.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: run `certutil -verify -urlfetch path\certfile.cer` command against your SSL certificate and post command output here.

Comment: Hi, that is the outpout (FYI i use a .pfx certificate):  `LoadCert(Cert) returned ASN1 unexpected end of data. 0x80093102 (ASN: 258 CRYPT_
E_ASN1_EOD)
CertUtil: -verify command FAILED: 0x80093102 (ASN: 258 CRYPT_E_ASN1_EOD)
CertUtil: ASN1 unexpected end of data.`

Comment: you should run the command against public part of the certificate (with .CER extension).